# Thinking about entering Russian Market, What do I need to know?

Tags: php, mysql, internationalization, special-characters

Our site may potentially have some Russian posters. What do I need to know (you can be really generic) as far as things like charsets to have our pages display properly, get indexed by Russian search engines, and be functional using Russian text?

Thanks

Comment: Good question. I'm watching this one.

Comment: Wouldn't this question fit better on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: He's wondering about encoding, etc., which is certainly in the realm of programmming.

Comment: Actually my vote was to move it to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/?as=1 - Q&A for professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set all your databases to UTF-8 and that's (almost) enough.
Also, you need to ensure that your code deals with chars in UTF-8 too.